# CTreeCtrl Checkbox Child item state

Tags: c++, checkbox, mfc

I have a CTreeCtrl with Checkbox. How can I make it work like standard app: 
+ When I select a root item, all its child iems will be selected, 
+ When I select a child item, its root item will be marked with a rectangle in the checkbox, and if all other childs of that root were already selected, it will be a check mark instead of the rectangle at the root item.

Comment: thanks leppie, I cant add the c++ tag

Answer (score 0):

It's not 'standard', you have to do all that manually.

Comment: thanks Roel, will search more for a solution. I said I wanted my app works like standard app. I didn't say that operation is standard anyway ^^.

Answer (score 0):

After several searches I found this on CodeProject. Hope anyone who meet the same issue  can find it could be in help

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/140828/A-Multi-selectable-Tree-Control-Supports-Transpare